# How to get distinct characters?

Tags: c#

I have a code like

```
string code = "AABBDDCCRRFF";
```

In this code, I want to retrieve only distinct characters

The Output should be like:

```
ANS: ABDCRF
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
string code = "AABBDDCCRRFF";
string answer = new String(code.Distinct().ToArray());
```

Comment: `string` already implements `IEnumerable<char>` so you can remove the call to `ToCharArray()`.

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: Thanks, have removed the ToCharArray(). In VS2008 it didn't come up in intelisense!

Comment: I really like this answer - it is the most concise.

Comment: @PeterKelly late comment but I leave it mostly for future readers: most concise but **wrong** unless OP's input is strictly limited to US ASCII (well also other answers do not mention they're picking distinct _code units_ instead of _characters_).

Comment: Applies to `List<char>` ?

Answer (score 10):

Linq's [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299412.aspx) returns distinct elements from a sequence. As the `String` class implements `IEnumerable<char>`, `Distinct` in this context returns an `IEnumerable<char>` containing all of the unique characters in the string.

```
code.Distinct();
```

Comment: Whoa, didn't realise you could Distinct straight from the string - nice.

Comment: @Mantorok - updated my answer with a bit more of an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative option using dotNet 2.0 compatible code:

```
public string RemoveDuplicateChars(string input)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(input);

    foreach (char c in input)
    {
        stringBuilder.Replace(c.ToString(), string.Empty)
                     .Append(c.ToString());
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about in linq:

```
var str = "AABBCCDDDDDDEEEEEFFF";
var unique = str.ToCharArray().Distinct();
Console.WriteLine("Answer: {0}.", string.Join(string.Empty, unique));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that provides the string and a count of the distinct characters...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StringDict
{
    class Program
    {
        static IDictionary<char, int> charDict =new Dictionary<char, int>();
        static private string _charStr = "s;ldfjgsl;dkkjfg;lsdkfjg;lsdkfjg;lsdkfjg;lsdkfj";
        private static int _outInt=0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var ch in _charStr)
            {
                if (!charDict.TryGetValue(ch,out _outInt))
                {
                    charDict.Add(new KeyValuePair<char, int>(ch,1));
                }
                else
                {
                    charDict[ch]++;
                }
            }
            Console.Write("Unique Characters: ");
            Console.WriteLine('\n');
            foreach (var kvp in charDict)
            {
                Console.Write(kvp.Key);
            }
            Console.WriteLine('\n');
            foreach (var kvp in charDict)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Char: "+kvp.Key+" Count: "+kvp.Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output...

```
Unique Characters:

s;ldfjgk

Char: s Count: 6
Char: ; Count: 6
Char: l Count: 6
Char: d Count: 6
Char: f Count: 6
Char: j Count: 6
Char: g Count: 5
Char: k Count: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows

```
var s = "AABBDDCCRRFF";
var result = s.Distinct();
var distinct = result.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, c) => current + c.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(distinct);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with grouping by characters...

```
var code="AABBDDCCRRFF";
var unique = string.Concat(text.GroupBy(a => a).Select(a => a.Key));
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all distinct characters I have used ascii array.
steps 1. Added ascii array of size 256, becuase max char ascii value is 255
step 2. increment each ascii to the location of particular alphabet's ascii value

please refer below code to understand.

```
public static class StringManipulation
{
  public static string UniqueChars(this string astrInputString)
  {
       astrInputString = astrInputString.ToLower();
    int[] arrAscii = new int[256];
    string lstrFinalOutput = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < astrInputString.Length; i++)
    {
        arrAscii[Convert.ToInt32(astrInputString[i])]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < astrInputString.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arrAscii[Convert.ToInt32(astrInputString[i])] == 1)
            lstrFinalOutput = lstrFinalOutput + astrInputString[i];
    }
    return lstrFinalOutput;
  }
}
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    string input = "AAssjjkkLLlx";
    Console.WriteLine("Unique Charcters in string " + input.UniqueChars());

  }
}
```

Click to Download this Code https://github.com/SiddharthBhamare/StringManipulation/blob/master/StringManipulation/Program.cs

Answer (score -2):

Just for the heck of it -- using a `StringBuilder`

```
 string code = "AABBDDCCRRFF";
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 code.Distinct().ToList().ForEach(c => sb.Append(c));
 MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```